# Is this a MapView Bug?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

I am implementing an app that uses Google Maps. During debugging I found an interesting error which you can easily reproduce (I hope). If you test the Hello MapView example from Google:

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

The error:
If you slide to any direction fast (try diagonal direction), for a period of time, you will probably get the following error:

```
02-28 15:59:45.138: D/dalvikvm(26484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 13% free 18870K/21639K,      paused 2ms+4ms
02-28 15:59:45.911: D/dalvikvm(26484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1603K, 20% free 17396K/21639K, paused 14ms
02-28 15:59:45.911: I/dalvikvm-heap(26484): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.546MB for 1560976-byte allocation
02-28 15:59:45.942: D/dalvikvm(26484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 13% free 18919K/21639K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-28 15:59:54.271: D/dalvikvm(26484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2794K, 19% free 17649K/21639K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-28 15:59:58.497: D/dalvikvm(26484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 856K, 18% free 17880K/21639K, paused 5ms+3ms
02-28 16:00:04.341: D/dalvikvm(26484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1003K, 17% free 18063K/21639K, paused 4ms+4ms
02-28 16:00:11.083: D/skia(26484): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 131072
02-28 16:00:11.091: D/skia(26484): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 131072
02-28 16:00:11.614: D/skia(26484): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 131072
02-28 16:00:11.614: D/skia(26484): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 131072
02-28 16:00:11.638: D/skia(26484): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 131072
02-28 16:00:11.646: D/dalvikvm(26484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1097K, 16% free 18222K/21639K, paused 2ms+6ms
02-28 16:00:11.646: D/skia(26484): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 131072
02-28 16:00:11.646: D/skia(26484): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 131072
```

The map crashes. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I tested this example on a Galaxy S2 smartphone and on Galaxy Nexus

Comment: But I guess this is not a real problem of your code. There is no error  there are just debug and information messages. Does this somehow influence on your code and user experience?

Comment: The problem is when you slide your fingers on the map (fast) the map crashes. The map is not usable anymore after the crash. When the map crashes i get the following message "imageref_ashmem create failed" (as you can see above). I think there are some memory issues. The code is the example code from the link i sent above. Can anyone reproduce this behavior?

Comment: I've tried today but application did not crash. For how long should I do this? Ashmem is Android kernel driver that is responsible for memory sharing.

Comment: If you do it for about two minutes it should crash. Try fast diagonal sliding. Thanks!

Comment: What is the result of the map crashing? Is the app force closing?

Comment: It seems to be a MapView bug, if everybody could start this issue maybe google starts working on the map view after not doing improvements for quite a long time: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=mapview%20memory&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=26546

Comment: i think @Yury u are right...this is not error..but ya i want to ask one thing that when i also run my google map program than i got some error in log but program was runing well...i think this might be google map error...if still confuse go for some other tutorial example rather than using this code...

Answer (score 1):

Think Google Maps crashes with [OutOfMemoryError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) I catched it few times on my HTC Wildfire. It can be easly reproduced on devices with small heap memory. When you slide (resize) fast you will exceed all your heap. Think that garbage collector in some cases can't release memory so fast and you running into out of memory.

Comment: What can be the solution besides using largeHeap="true"?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, intermittent crash behavior using MapView can be solved by ensuring that you have specified using **largeHeap** in the "application" element of your application manifest, especially on larger screen devices (tablets). This attribute is available starting in API Level 11 (Android 3.0).

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.ge.android.app"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/app" android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true"
                 android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
                 android:largeHeap="true">
    ...
    </application>
   ...
</manifest>
```

See Also: [Android Developer Guide - Android Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap)